# How to configure gpg to enter passphrase only once per session

Tags: xfce, gpg

Is it posible to configure `gpg` in a way that I enter passphrase only once, and it will work for the whole session (I'm using `Ubuntu/XFce`)?

I'm not sure how `gpg` works, it seems that the default function is that `gpg` asks `gpg-agent` for the passphrase and the agent runs pin-entry to ask for passphrase.

I would like to use pinentry-curses only once per session, so I can paste my passphrase (I have `hex` string from a sentence - I use `echo -n <SENTENCE> | str-hex`) and sign email from Claws Mail without putting passphrase (you can't use pinentry-curses with Claws Mail).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the technique described on this page:

http://fvue.nl/wiki/Debian_4.0:_Installing_gpg-agent

Here's the gist:

1. Install gpg-agent and pinentry program:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnupg-agent pinentry-curses
   ```
2. Add the lines below to `~/.profile`. Any POSIX-confirming shell should include this file.

   ```
   # Invoke GnuPG-Agent the first time we login.
   # Does `~/.gpg-agent-info' exist and points to gpg-agent process accepting signals?
   if test -f $HOME/.gpg-agent-info && \
       kill -0 `cut -d: -f 2 $HOME/.gpg-agent-info` 2>/dev/null; then
       GPG_AGENT_INFO=`cat $HOME/.gpg-agent-info | cut -c 16-`
   else
       # No, gpg-agent not available; start gpg-agent
       eval `gpg-agent --daemon --no-grab --write-env-file $HOME/.gpg-agent-info`
   fi
   export GPG_TTY=`tty`
   export GPG_AGENT_INFO
   ```

   This little script will be activated when you login. If the agent is not running, it will be started. When the agent is started, it shows how to set environment variables in order to connect to it. The script saves these values in `~/.gpg-agent-info`, so that when you start another login session the script can setup the variables correctly and thus use the agent.

You will only have to enter your passphrase once per boot. The agent will store your keys in memory, so you don't have to enter the passphrase again.

Comment: I'd been using this script happily, but it would fail randomly.  Eventually, I modified the conditional to this
``GPG_PROCESS=`cut -d: -f 2 $HOME/.gpg-agent-info`
if  test -f $HOME/.gpg-agent-info && \
    kill -0 ${GPG_PROCESS}  2>/dev/null && \
    [[ ${GPG_PROCESS} == `pgrep -x -u "${USER}" gpg-agent` ]] ; then``
and it worked fine.  The problem is that the script above checks if the process in `.gpg-agent-info` is alive and accepts signals with `kill -0`.  If a process is there, but not `gpg-agent`, we get the wrong behavior.  The attached code checks we have the right process.