# GPG Problems When Releasing With Leiningen

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I'm trying to use `lein release` ([default](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen), not [the plugin](https://github.com/relaynetwork/lein-release)).

Now, I've installed gpg-agent and pinentry-curses, and gotten to the point where a separate curses screen appears, asking me for my secret key. However, the screen does not respond to my key inputs and just hangs there. I have to interrupt (Ctrl-c) the dialog to get back keyboard responsiveness. Now, I've been following these guides, but haven't been able to solve this problem yet. Any insights?

- https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html
- [How to configure gpg to enter passphrase only once per session](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46960/how-to-configure-gpg-to-enter-passphrase-only-once-per-session)
- http://fvue.nl/wiki/Debian_4.0:_Installing_gpg-agent

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem specifically on OS/X and leiningen's ability to read from stdin after forking.

The user workaround is to use `gpg-agent` (best to install using Homebrew `brew install gpg-agent`) and enter the passphrase prior to executing leiningen with commands that require GPG interaction (e.g. `lein vcs tag` which is used by `lein release` by default)

A github issue that tracks it is [1674](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1674).